# Why is react native running differently on device than simulator?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I have background audio playback functional on the iOS simulator - but when I build the app on my device neither the Now Playing nor background playback function. Any clue what could be causing this issue?

Comment: inspect on browser console, does it shows any error ?

Comment: @ParthGhiya Nope no errors on the browser console. Really have no clue what could be going wrong.